# Onclick in Tool bar is not working

Tags: android, menu, onclick, toolbar

Hi guys I am using badge in toolbar and I set count and its working fine.
but  only the problem is clickable function is not working

Here is my code

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
View badgeLayoutView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.badge));
    basketCount = (TextView) badgeLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
    CommonUtil.dbUtil.open();

    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        MainActivity.basketCount.setText(CommonUtil.dbUtil.countCart());
    } finally {
        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    invalidateOptionsMenu();


    badgeLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

and my xml is

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/badge"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.RelativeLayout"
    android:title="Badges"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/view_badge_layout"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: Why are you calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()`?

Comment: @Shaishav if i not call that, thn i cant able to set the textview

Comment: I see that your `basketCount` textview is static in the activity, that probably makes your app susceptible to memory leak. Avoid anything that uses `context` be declared static. Since, its a `TextView` you shouldn't have to call invaidate() on your options menu because `setText()` will itself call `invalidate()` in your textview.